# Ler arquivo word em laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, microsoft-word, laravel-5.3

Galera estou com uma dificuldade em ler um arquivo Word no laravel, a situação é a seguinte:

Tenho um formulário onde uma pessoa adiciona um arquivo word em um campo input type file. Quero pegar o texto desse word, separar em uma variável para posteriormente gravar no banco. Isto é possível ?

Comment: Talvez isto ajude: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31627389/phpword-in-laravel-5

Comment: Então, eu procurei sobre esta biblioteca, porém é só de escrita (geração de um novo word) .. no caso eu já tenho um word pronto, eu só queria pegar o texto e guardar um em uma variável.

Comment: E esta solução? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19503653/how-to-extract-text-from-word-file-doc-docx-xlsx-pptx-php

Comment: Esta solução também só está escrevendo e não lendo ...

Comment: Uma dúvida, esse upload precisa mesmo ser em docx?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar a biblioteca [PHPWord](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord) pra fazer isso. Basta você instalar ela via Composer e utilizá-la juntamente com o Laravel (no link da biblioteca há melhores instruções de instalação e uso).

Segue exemplos de uso:

- https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/tree/develop/samples

Comment: Cara eu pensei nisso aqui : https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/develop/samples/Sample_11_ReadWord2007.php mas de fato não ajuda muito também .. é um dos exemplos da biblioteca

Comment: Mas o que você precisa afinal de contas? Você quer apenas transformar o arquivo enviado via upload em texto?

Comment: Vamos supor que acabei de criar um texto dentro de um arquivo word, vou pegar esse word e fazer o upload em um formulário em meu site, após isso o sistema recebe aquele arquivo, entra no arquivo, pega o texto que foi digitado e armazena em uma variável... Teria como fazer isso ?

Comment: @DaniloTiagoThaiSantos eu acho que já fiz algo assim, estou tentando relembrar. Te passo assim que eu estiver mais tranquilo.

Comment: Ah legal ! estou no aguardo.